# How to get documents with an array that contains a string? Cloud Firestore & Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I have looked everywhere online and I just can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.

What I am trying to achieve is to find all users that have the same device under their devices. 
Here is the structure of the Firestore database:
[Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcuYI.png)

So recently Firebase released version 5.3.0 of their Javascript library which in their release notes states:

> Added 'array-contains' query operator for use with .where() to find documents where an array field contains a specific element.

[Firebase Javascript Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js)

I am trying to use this 'array-contains' in the .where() but i am getting no success. Here is my code:
    `admin.firestore().collection("users").where("devices",'array-contains', id)
//I get id from another place, i know that id is valid`

This is the error i get back from the firebase functions log:

> Unhandled error Error: Argument "opStr" is not a valid FieldComparison. Operator must be one of "<", "<=", "==", ">", or ">=".
>       at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as isFieldComparison] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:89:23)
>       at CollectionReference.where (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1095:18)
>       at exports.checkIfDeviceIdValid.functions.https.onCall (/user_code/index.js:23:50)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:330:32
>       at next (native)
>       at fulfilled (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:25:58)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Here are my dependencies from my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.15.4",
"firebase-admin": "~5.13.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.0.2"
}
```

If someone could help me with this and show me an example of how to do this I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You say you want to use version 5.3.0 of the javascript library, but you're showing firebase-admin in your package.json.  Are you writing frontend or backend code here?  firebase-admin is for backend code only.

Comment: This is backend code @Doug Stevenson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Version 6.0.0 - August 9, 2018](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node) of the Firebase Admin Node.js SDK have the `array-contains` feature.

Answer (score 3):

Doug already hinted at the answer in his comment - the adminSDK that you are using does not yet support `array-contains`. The adminSDK is different than the JavaScriptSDK... which can definitely be confusing since you use JS language to utilize the adminSDK. [This release-notes page](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) does a good job demonstrating the fact that they are two separate things.

- The JavaScript SDK is for front-end.
- The Admin SDK is for backend (*typically FB cloud functions*).

Unfortunately, there's no clean way to accomplish what you're looking for on the backend. If you were doing it on the front end, you'd be able to use that handy `array-contains` feature the JavaScript SDK team just put out. If you **have** to do it on the backend, I can't think of any way other than to painfully query the whole thing and loop over the values.

There are a few alternatives to that nasty approach:

1. If you can, move that query to the front end and take advantage of the JS-SDK's new `array-contains` feature.
2. Restructure your database to avoid using the array.
3. (*not a serious option*) Wait for the adminSDK team to implement this feature.

Comment: Bummer. Well I guess I’ll have to just wait for them to add it to the admin ask. :(

Answer (score 3):

As Doug and JeremyW have mentioned, this feature is not implemented on the adminSDK. You can restructure your database by making the devices array into a collection on the same level as the users collection. Each document in that collection will contain a device number and the id of the user. You would then be able to query the needed information:

```
const ids = admin.firestore().collection("devices").where("number",'==', id).select("id").get();
ids.forEach(id =>{
    admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(id)...
});
```

You can get more ideas from Frank van Puffelen's answer on [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Okay I implemented what you recommended and it works. I would select this answer as the correct answer but it wasn't what I wanted in means of the firestorm functionality. I do greatly appreciate this answer.

Comment: Lets assume we 1000 users with that device listed. Does this query count 1000 reads (on the users collection) towards the api limit?

Comment: You will only be charge for the amount of documents that you receive back from the query. Assuming you perform `const ids = admin.firestore().collection("devices").where(...).get();` and get back 1000 user ids then you will be charge for 1000 reads. Additionally, in the users collection, if you would perform a search for each user id received, then you would perform another 1000 reads. In total, you would perform 2000 reads. For more information on cloud firestore pricing, check out this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NegFl9p_sE)

Answer (score 0):

Using the following configuration, the array-contains operator works fine:

```
"firebase-admin": "8.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",

"engines":
    "node": "8"
```